# How to send call log details via email

Tags: android, email, calllog

The below code will show the last one week call log details.But i want to send that call log details to my gmail-id "jegadesh9531@gmail.com. Anyone please tell me that what changes i have to do in this code to get the call log details to my e-mail.

```js
 private String getCallDetails()
    {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
        Date weekBefore = calendar.getTime();
        String selection = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?";
        String [] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(weekBefore.getTime())};
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
}
int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        stringBuffer.append("Call Log :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long
                    .parseLong(callDate)));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dirCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dirCode)
            {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE :
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED CALL";
                    break;

            }
          stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phoneNumber + "\nCall Type:--- "
                    + dir + "\nCall Date:---"
                    + dateString + "\nCall Duration:---" + callDuration);
            stringBuffer.append("\n--------------------------");
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: is this code return you your call logs?..you are not updating you stringBuffer with the callLogs. you can send the whole string in text type.

Comment: I couldn't find any line of code where you are saving the call log details.

Comment: The above code will return last one week call log details.......but i want to send that call log details to my email. i want that call log details to the text body of my gmail account.  How to add call log details to this line....intent.putExtra(Intent.Extra_Text,"  ");

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "jegadesh9531@gmail.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hi,");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Call Logs "+stringBuffer.toString());
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

I hope it will helps you :)